# How to pull first row of the group and use filter to get results using "not"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to pull the first row of the group. For my problem, I am trying to sort by the scheduled tread code then whether it is scheduled or alternative and only pull the first row of the group. I am also trying to filter `Loc.BKT` is not `HDL`.

This is how I am doing it but it is not working.

```
Select FAC,
       Cosw.Tread_Code as Scheduled_Tread_Code,
       SPEC_NEW.Tread_Code,
       Case When cosw.tread_code = spec_new.tread_code Then 'Scheduled' 
       else 'Alternative' end AS Size, 
       COUNT(Distinct loc.serial )  QTY 
FROM [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work] cosw with (nolock)
Inner Join [SharedData].dbo.spec_master Spec with (nolock) On spec.spec=Cosw.SPEC
Inner Join [SharedData].dbo.spec_master SPEC_NEW with (nolock) On SPEC_NEW.ARTICLE=SPEC.article
Inner Join [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Locator] LOC with (Nolock) ON LOC.SPEC=SPEC_NEW.SPEC
Where Cosw.FAC='pe19' and Loc.BKT not in ('HDL') 
GROUP BY FAC, cosw.Tread_Code, SPec_new.Tread_Code
```

Comment: Check out SQL row_number and partition by, that should put you in direction of what you need.

Comment: The code looks like SQL Server, so I added the tag.  If this is not correct, you should fix the tag -- and in general tag your questions with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output - "it's not working" is not easy to help with.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output in text

Comment: Got it to work, thanks guys

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Brad I got it to work by doing

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY FAC, Cosw.Tread_Code
                 ORDER BY fac, Cosw.Tread_Code,Case When cosw.tread_code = spec_new.tread_code Then 'Scheduled' else 'Alternative' end DESC
           ) AS r_num
```